# SDK AWS and Lambda functions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm using the AWS SDK with Visual Studio 2017

Trying to compile a predefine Lambda example (AWS Lambda project .NET core) I have this error:

```
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.1. Either target .NET Core 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.1
```

Also, you can see that NuGet dependencies doesn't work correctly:

[image: NuGet]

To solve the first error I go to project properties and choose .Net Core 2.0

But the NuGet dependencies are still wrong and now when I try to compile it again I got this error:

```
 run nuget package restore to generate this file C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.104\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets
```

I have tried to delete this NuGet packages and install again but I can not.

I developed using other AWS SDK's samples and all goes good, I only have the problem with AWS Lambda samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the `AWS Toolkit for Visual Studio 2017` extension and can create a new AWS Lambda project (empty function) and build this fine targeting .netcore 2.1. I would double check your installation of the .netcore SDK, the version of the AWS extension/templates and see if that helps.

Comment: It's quite weird because if I open visual studio from the begining and after that I creat a Lambda function with the AWS SDK the dependencies update automatically, but if I open other project while visual studio is opening with other project, the dependencies doesn't update